# Can't upload files to Owncloud after changing storage directory

Tags: linux, virtualbox, permissions, owncloud

I am using Owncloud via the Bitnami VM and only had about 17 GB of space. I created a 150 GB (dynamic sized for expanding later) .vdi and connected it to the VM. I then followed all the procedures for mounting, etc. The new disk is mounted as `/data` and I have correctly edited the `config.php` file to point to the new directory. I *also* correctly moved all files (.ocdata, .locks, etc.) to the new directory and can log into the owncloud and see all previous filed etc.

EXCEPT:

I am not able to upload anything. It says `You don't have permission to upload or create files here` at the top of the screen. Any ideas how to change this?

Answer (score 0):

This may not fix your problem but it would be the first thing I'd check.

You need to make sure that all files in your data folder have read, write, execute permissions for the user that runs the webserver you're using. In the case of an Apache server the default user is "www-data". Users for other servers are easily found using google.

You can easily change the permissions using the "sudo chown -R" command on your data folder.